# Haskell - read string from keyboard

Tags: haskell

I am trying to read a string from keyboard. This is my code so far:

```
getLine :: IO String
getLine = do x <- getChar if x=='\n' then return [] else do xs<-getLine return (x:xs)
```

The problem is that I get this error when compiling:

> parse error on input 'if'

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to insist on writing everything on one line, you'll need to insert a semicolon between consecutive statements in `do` blocks:

```
getLine = do x <- getChar; if x=='\n' then return [] else do xs<-getLine; return (x:xs)
                         ^ here                                         ^ and here
```

It would be better to just split the whole thing across multiple lines, though:

```
getLine = do x <- getChar
             if x=='\n' then return []
                        else do xs<-getLine
                                return (x:xs)
```